# How to retrieve complex type object using ksoap2

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, webservices-client

According to [this tutorial](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html) I have developed an app to retrieving data from a web service.

In web service, it will get some list of id and returning a SingleAddWithThumbnail class object.

**WSDL (JAX-WS)**

```
<xs:element name="getAddCardResponse" type="tns:getAddCardResponse"/>

<xs:element name="getCardDetails" type="tns:getCardDetails"/>

<xs:element name="getCardDetailsResponse" type="tns:getCardDetailsResponse"/>

<xs:complexType name="getAddCard">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="idList" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="getAddCardResponse">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="return" type="tns:singleAddWithThumbnail" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="singleAddWithThumbnail">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="addID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  <xs:element name="addTitle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  <xs:element name="shopName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  <xs:element name="shopNo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
  <xs:element name="thumbnailPic" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

**SingleAddWithThumbnail class**

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;

public class SingleAddWithThumbnail implements KvmSerializable{

    String thumbnailPic;
    String addID;
    String shopNo;
    String shopName;
    String addTitle;

    public SingleAddWithThumbnail() {

    }

    public SingleAddWithThumbnail(String thumbnailPic, String addID,
            String shopNo, String shopName,String addTitle) {

    this.thumbnailPic = thumbnailPic;
    this.addID = addID;
    this.shopNo = shopNo;
    this.shopName = shopName;
    this.addTitle = addTitle;
}

public String getAddTitle() {
    return addTitle;
}

public void setAddTitle(String addTitle) {
    this.addTitle = addTitle;
}

public String getThumbnailPic() {
    return thumbnailPic;
}

public void setThumbnailPic(String thumbnailPic) {
    this.thumbnailPic = thumbnailPic;
}

public String getAddID() {
    return addID;
}

public void setAddID(String addID) {
    this.addID = addID;
}

public String getShopNo() {
    return shopNo;
}

public void setShopNo(String shopNo) {
    this.shopNo = shopNo;
}

public String getShopName() {
    return shopName;
}

public void setShopName(String shopName) {
    this.shopName = shopName;
}


@Override
public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

    switch (arg0) {

    case 0:         
        return thumbnailPic;
    case 1:         
        return addID;
    case 2:         
        return shopNo;
    case 3:         
        return shopName;
    case 4:         
        return addTitle;
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getPropertyCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 5;
}

@Override
public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        break;
    case 1:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        break;
    case 2:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        break;
    case 3:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        break;
    case 4:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        break;

        default:break;

    }
}

@Override
public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (index) {

    case 0:
        thumbnailPic = value.toString();
        break;
    case 1:
        addID = value.toString();
        break;
    case 2:
        shopNo = value.toString();
        break;
    case 3:
        shopName = value.toString();
        break;
    case 4:
        addTitle = value.toString();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
}
```

**Activity Class**

```
public class WebServiceObjectPassingActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<String> idListOfDownalodedAdds = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_service_object_passing);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.testId);
    tv.setText("testing");
    SingleAddWithThumbnail t;
    TumbImageLoadingTask task = new TumbImageLoadingTask();
    task.execute(idListOfDownalodedAdds);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {     
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.web_service_object_passing, menu);
    return true;
}
class TumbImageLoadingTask extends
        AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, SingleAddWithThumbnail> {

    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://lba.anjula.com/";
    private final String URL ="http://112.135.136.3:8080/LBAServi/LBAServiWSDL";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://lba.anjula.com/getAddCard";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "getAddCard";



    @Override
    protected SingleAddWithThumbnail doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... arg0 )      {

        SingleAddWithThumbnail result = new SingleAddWithThumbnail();
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        PropertyInfo idListPropety = new PropertyInfo();

        idListPropety.setName("idList");
        idListPropety.setValue(arg0[0]);
        idListPropety.setType(arg0[0].getClass());
        request.addProperty(idListPropety);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        //envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "SingleAddWithThumbnail",
                SingleAddWithThumbnail.class);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);


        try {
            androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            result.setThumbnailPic(response.getProperty(0).toString());
            result.setAddID(response.getProperty(1).toString());
            result.setShopNo(response.getProperty(2).toString());
            result.setShopName(response.getProperty(3).toString());
            result.setAddTitle(response.getProperty(4).toString());

            Log.i("WebService:::",
                    "Result Card Returning Id:" + result.getAddID());

            return result;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(SingleAddWithThumbnail result) {

        Log.i("WebServicePOSTEX:::",
                "Result Card Returning Id:" + result.getAddID());

    }

}

}
```

When running app it is giving these errors.

```
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: [Ljava.util.ArrayList;@41034f78
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:664)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeProperty(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:649)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:595)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:573)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:658)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:555)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.write(SoapEnvelope.java:205)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.createRequestData(Transport.java:134)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:144)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:116)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:111)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at com.example.webserviceobjectpassing.WebServiceObjectPassingActivity$TumbImageLoadingTask.doInBackground(WebServiceObjectPassingActivity.java:84)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at com.example.webserviceobjectpassing.WebServiceObjectPassingActivity$TumbImageLoadingTask.doInBackground(WebServiceObjectPassingActivity.java:1)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
10-04 10:20:52.713: E/AndroidRuntime(2218): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Why is this error occurring and how can I fix this ?

Comment: I changed the ArrayList<String> idListOfDownalodedAdds in to a String. now the code is working without any error.

Comment: http://binarylifebyanjula.blogspot.com/2013/11/android-webservices-ksoap2-complex.html